# Chain rule for multiple variables

Tags: multivariable-calculus, derivatives

If a $C^1$ function $f(u,v)$ has the following partial derivatives
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} (u,v) = 2uv \\ \frac{\partial f}{\partial v} (u,v) = u^2$$
and we have $g(t) =f(2t,t^2)$, what is $g'(t)$?

Trying to understand the chain rule, and it's worked out fine so far but am having problems with this one.

Comment: Let $h\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R^2, t\mapsto (h_1,h_2)$ where $h_1\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R, t\mapsto 2t$ and $h_2\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R, t\mapsto t^2$. You want to find $g'$ which equals $(f\circ h)'$. The chain rule tells you that $$\forall t\in \mathbb R\left[g'(t)=\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial _1}(h(t))h_1'(t)+\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial _2}(h(t))h_2'(t)\right].$$ Here $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial _k}$ denotes the partial derivative of $f$ with respect to its $k^\text{th}$ coordinate.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, it should be straighforward enough to see that if given those partial derivatives above; then
\begin{equation}
f(u, v) = u^{2}v + C
\end{equation}
Now according to the change of variable;
\begin{equation}
u=2t, v=t^{2}
\end{equation}
We find that
\begin{eqnarray}
g(t) &=& f(2t, t^{2}) + C \\
     &=& (2t)^{2}t^{2}+ C \\
     &=& 4t^{4} + C
\end{eqnarray}

And the derivative from there is straighforward. Alternatively, using the chain rule (as you specified); we can write
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{dg}{dt} &=& \frac{df}{dt}(2t, t^{2}) \\
              &=& \frac{\partial f}{\partial u}\frac{du}{dt}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} \frac{dv}{dt}
\end{eqnarray}
And simply fill in the blanks from there.

All the best,
A